# Target wsgi script will not load properly

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am trying to deploy a Django web server with mod_wsgi and apache2 and I am getting an internal server error.

```
[Sun Mar 29 16:13:00.382493 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1194:tid 139655348275072] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Mar 29 16:13:00.382514 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1194:tid 139655348275072] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Mar 29 20:13:03.159156 2015] [:error] [pid 26383:tid 139655211136768] [remote 71.88.97.195:25099] mod_wsgi (pid=26383): Target WSGI script '/var/www/mbusuite/mbusuite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Mar 29 20:13:03.159199 2015] [:error] [pid 26383:tid 139655211136768] [remote 71.88.97.195:25099] mod_wsgi (pid=26383): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/mbusuite/mbusuite/wsgi.py'.
[Sun Mar 29 20:13:03.159221 2015] [:error] [pid 26383:tid 139655211136768] [remote 71.88.97.195:25099] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Mar 29 20:13:03.159258 2015] [:error] [pid 26383:tid 139655211136768] [remote 71.88.97.195:25099]   File "/var/www/mbusuite/mbusuite/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Sun Mar 29 20:13:03.159317 2015] [:error] [pid 26383:tid 139655211136768] [remote 71.88.97.195:25099]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Sun Mar 29 20:13:03.159329 2015] [:error] [pid 26383:tid 139655211136768] [remote 71.88.97.195:25099]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
[Sun Mar 29 20:13:03.159368 2015] [:error] [pid 26383:tid 139655211136768] [remote 71.88.97.195:25099]     django.setup()
[Sun Mar 29 20:13:03.159379 2015] [:error] [pid 26383:tid 139655211136768] [remote 71.88.97.195:25099]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
[Sun Mar 29 20:13:03.159415 2015] [:error] [pid 26383:tid 139655211136768] [remote 71.88.97.195:25099]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Sun Mar 29 20:13:03.159427 2015] [:error] [pid 26383:tid 139655211136768] [remote 71.88.97.195:25099]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
[Sun Mar 29 20:13:03.159563 2015] [:error] [pid 26383:tid 139655211136768] [remote 71.88.97.195:25099]     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
[Sun Mar 29 20:13:03.159575 2015] [:error] [pid 26383:tid 139655211136768] [remote 71.88.97.195:25099]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 87, in create
[Sun Mar 29 20:13:03.159654 2015] [:error] [pid 26383:tid 139655211136768] [remote 71.88.97.195:25099]     module = import_module(entry)
[Sun Mar 29 20:13:03.159665 2015] [:error] [pid 26383:tid 139655211136768] [remote 71.88.97.195:25099]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[Sun Mar 29 20:13:03.159708 2015] [:error] [pid 26383:tid 139655211136768] [remote 71.88.97.195:25099]     __import__(name)
[Sun Mar 29 20:13:03.159739 2015] [:error] [pid 26383:tid 139655211136768] [remote 71.88.97.195:25099] ImportError: No module named storage
```

My apache config file is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mbusuite.duckdns.org
    WSGIDaemonProcess mbusuite.duckdns.org python-path=/var/www/mbusuite:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup mbusuite.duckdns.org
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mbusuite/mbusuite/wsgi.py process-group=mbusuite.duckdns.org
    ServerAdmin mbu@wpi.edu

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    #<Directory /var/www/mbusuite/static>
    #       Require all granted
    #</Directory>
    #<Directory /var/www/mbusuite/core>
    #       Require all granted
    #</Directory>
    #<Directory /var/www/mbusuite/templates>
    #       Require all granted
    #</Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/mbusuite/>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And the wsgi.py is

```
"""
WSGI config for mbusuite project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os
import sys
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "mbusuite.settings"

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I am not quite sure if this is a permissions issue or a configuration issue. Any help at all would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can specify process group on the WSGIScriptAlias directive, and your python-path directive must match what you have in your wsgi.py file (i.e. `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` must be importable from the python path you specify).  You shouldn't give permissions to the wsgi.py file (ideally you wouldn't have your source under /var/www either since that's usually Apache's docroot area -- and you don't want any possibility of serving your raw source). Something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mbusuite.duckdns.org
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mbusuite/mbusuite/wsgi.py 
    WSGIProcessGroup mbusuite.duckdns.org
    WSGIDaemonProcess mbusuite.duckdns.org \
        python-path=/var/www:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

    ServerAdmin mbu@wpi.edu

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

should work with your current wsgi.py (you might have to declare a docroot too -- you can use it to e.g. serve `favicon.ico` files ;-)

Comment: Both process-group and application-group are valid options to WSGIScriptAlias directive. When used you do not need the separate WSGIProcessGroup and WSGIApplicationGroup directives.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton do you have a reference? (I'm looking at https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIScriptAlias and it's not mentioned there..)

Comment: Only mentioned in the release notes. Gave up trying to update documentation in a timely manner because Linux distributions shipped versions which were years out of date anyway. Was little point having it documented and then deal with all the users complaining it didn't work. For various reasons the mod_wsgi documentation has since languished so never have got back to updating documentation. See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/master/release-notes/version-3.0.html

Comment: Learned something new today too ;-)  Thanks for all your solid work on mod_wsgi btw.